# retrieve pdf blob from database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, blob

Well I need to store a content of pdf to database and retrieve it.
I'm using fpdf to construct content of my pdf.
When I'm using $pdf->Output("","I"); or $pdf->Output("","D"); , I can see the content and save into my database.
My code is that:
          class FPDF extends tFPDF
                                {

```
                                function Header()
                            {
                                $hoje = date("d/m/y");
                                $this->Cell(10,10,"$hoje",0,'L');
                                $this->Image('./images/logo.png',170,10,30);

                                $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);

                                $this->Cell(70);

                                $this->Cell(30,10,'Nome da empresa',0,'C');

                                $this->Ln(15);
                            }

                                function NomeComprador($nomeUser,$apelido,$nomeCategoria)
                                {

                                    $this->SetFont('DejaVu','',10);

                                    $this->Cell(0,4,"Nome do Utilizador: $nomeUser" . " $apelido",0,1,'C');
                                    $this->Cell(-1);
                                    $this->Cell(0,5,"Categoria: $nomeCategoria",0,1,'C');

                                    $this->Ln(4);
                                }

                                function informacaoImagem($nomeImagem,$titulo,$descricao,$poupa,$desconto,$quantidade){

                                $this->nomeImagem = $nomeImagem;
                                $total = $quantidade * $poupa;
                                $this->Image('./images/paginaPrincipal/' . $this->nomeImagem,30,50,50);
                                $this->Cell(125,30,"Nome do Voucher: $titulo",0,1,'R');
                                $this->Cell(120.5,-15,"Descrição: $descricao",0,1,'R');
                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','B',22);
                                $this->Cell(180,40,"$total" . " €",0,1,'C');
                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','',11);
                                $this->Cell(250,-45,"Desconto: $desconto" . '%',0,1,'C');                               
                                }

                                function informacaoOferta($menus,$descricoes){

                                    foreach ($menus as $key => $value) {
                                            foreach ($descricoes as $key2 => $value2){
                                                if($key == 0 && $key2 == 0){
                                                    $valor = strip_tags($value2);
                                                    $this->SetFont('DejaVu', 'B', 14);
                                                    $this->Cell(125,100,"$value:",0,1,'L');
                                                    $this->SetFont('DejaVu','','11');
                                                    $this->Write(5,$this->Cell(125,-75,"$valor"));
                                                    $this->Ln(10);
                                            }elseif ($key == 1 && $key2 == 1){
                                                $valorFinal = strip_tags($value2);
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','B',13);
                                                $this->Cell(125,-30,"$value:",0,1,'L');
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','','11');
                                                $this->Write(5,"$valorFinal");
                                                $this->Ln(50);
                                            }elseif($key == 2 && $key2 == 2){
                                                $valor3 = strip_tags($value2);
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','B',13);
                                                $this->Cell(125,-50,"$value:",0,1,'L');
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','','11');
                                                $this->Write(7,"$valor3");
                                                $this->Ln(30);
                                            }elseif($key == 3 && $key2 == 3){
                                                $valor4 = strip_tags($value2);
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','B',13);
                                                $this->Cell(125,-10,"$value:",0,1,'L');
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','','11');
                                                $this->Write(3,"$valor4");
                                                $this->Ln(40);
                                            }elseif($key == 4 && $key2 == 4){
                                                $valor5 = strip_tags($value2);
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','B',13);
                                                $this->Cell(125,20,"$value:",0,1,'L');
                                                $this->SetFont('DejaVu','','11');
                                                $this->Write(0,"$valor5");
                                                $this->Ln(20);
                                            }
                                        }                           
                                    }
                                }

                                function EAN13($x, $y, $barcode, $h=16, $w=.35)
                                    {
                                        $this->Barcode($x,$y,$barcode,$h,$w,13);
                                    }

                                    function UPC_A($x, $y, $barcode, $h=16, $w=.35)
                                    {
                                        $this->Barcode($x,$y,$barcode,$h,$w,12);
                                    }

                                    function GetCheckDigit($barcode)
                                    {

                                        $sum=0;
                                        for($i=1;$i<=11;$i+=2)
                                            $sum+=3*$barcode[$i];
                                        for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+=2)
                                            $sum+=$barcode[$i];
                                        $r=$sum%10;
                                        if($r>0)
                                            $r=10-$r;
                                        return $r;
                                    }

                                    function TestCheckDigit($barcode)
                                    {

                                        $sum=0;
                                        for($i=1;$i<=11;$i+=2)
                                            $sum+=3*$barcode[$i];
                                        for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+=2)
                                            $sum+=$barcode[$i];
                                        return ($sum+$barcode[12])%10==0;
                                    }

                                    function Barcode($x, $y, $barcode, $h, $w, $len)
                                    {

                                        $barcode=str_pad($barcode,$len-1,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
                                        if($len==12)
                                            $barcode='0'.$barcode;

                                        if(strlen($barcode)==12)
                                            $barcode.=$this->GetCheckDigit($barcode);
                                        elseif(!$this->TestCheckDigit($barcode))
                                            $this->Error('Incorrect check digit');

                                        $codes=array(
                                            'A'=>array(
                                                '0'=>'0001101','1'=>'0011001','2'=>'0010011','3'=>'0111101','4'=>'0100011',
                                                '5'=>'0110001','6'=>'0101111','7'=>'0111011','8'=>'0110111','9'=>'0001011'),
                                            'B'=>array(
                                                '0'=>'0100111','1'=>'0110011','2'=>'0011011','3'=>'0100001','4'=>'0011101',
                                                '5'=>'0111001','6'=>'0000101','7'=>'0010001','8'=>'0001001','9'=>'0010111'),
                                            'C'=>array(
                                                '0'=>'1110010','1'=>'1100110','2'=>'1101100','3'=>'1000010','4'=>'1011100',
                                                '5'=>'1001110','6'=>'1010000','7'=>'1000100','8'=>'1001000','9'=>'1110100')
                                            );
                                        $parities=array(
                                            '0'=>array('A','A','A','A','A','A'),
                                            '1'=>array('A','A','B','A','B','B'),
                                            '2'=>array('A','A','B','B','A','B'),
                                            '3'=>array('A','A','B','B','B','A'),
                                            '4'=>array('A','B','A','A','B','B'),
                                            '5'=>array('A','B','B','A','A','B'),
                                            '6'=>array('A','B','B','B','A','A'),
                                            '7'=>array('A','B','A','B','A','B'),
                                            '8'=>array('A','B','A','B','B','A'),
                                            '9'=>array('A','B','B','A','B','A')
                                            );
                                        $code='101';
                                        $p=$parities[$barcode[0]];
                                        for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
                                            $code.=$codes[$p[$i-1]][$barcode[$i]];
                                        $code.='01010';
                                        for($i=7;$i<=12;$i++)
                                            $code.=$codes['C'][$barcode[$i]];
                                        $code.='101';

                                        for($i=0;$i<strlen($code);$i++)
                                        {
                                            if($code[$i]=='1')
                                                $this->Rect($x+$i*$w,$y,$w,$h,'F');
                                        }

                                        $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
                                        $this->Text($x,$y+$h+11/$this->k,substr($barcode,-$len));
                                    }

                                function PrintComprador($nomeUser,$apelido,$nomeCategoria,$titulo,$nomeImagem,$descricao,$poupa,$desconto,$quantidade)
                                {
                                    $this->AddPage();
                                    $this->NomeComprador($nomeUser,$apelido,$nomeCategoria);
                                    $this->informacaoImagem($nomeImagem,$titulo,$descricao,$poupa,$desconto,$quantidade);

                                }

                                function PrintOferta($menus,$descricoes)
                                {
                                    $this->informacaoOferta($menus,$descricoes);
                                }

                                    function Footer()
                                    {

                                    $this->SetY(-15);

                                    $this->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 8);

                                    $this->Cell(0,10,'Página '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
                                    }
                                }   
                                $pdf = new FPDF();
                                $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
                                $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu', 'B', 'DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', true);
                                $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 14);
                                $pdf->AliasNbPages();
                                for($i = 0; $i < $quantidade; $i++){
                                    $pdf->PrintComprador($nomeUser,$apelido,$nomeCategoria,$titulo,$nomeImagem,$descricao,$poupa,$desconto,$quantidade);
                                    $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,12);
                                    $pdf->EAN13(40,20,$random);
                                    $pdf->PrintOferta($menus,$descricoes);
                                    $pdf->Write(40,"Para descobrir a localização, descubra ");
                                    $pdf->SetFont('','U');
                                    $link = $pdf->AddLink();
                                    $pdf->Write(40,'aqui',$hiperlink);
                                    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', 'B', 12);
                                    $pdf->Ln(2);
                                    $pdf->Write(70,"Procedimento:");
                                    $pdf->Ln(2);
                                    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 11);
                                    $pdf->Write(90,"1- Imprimir o cupão.");
                                    $pdf->Ln(2);
                                    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 11);
                                    $pdf->Write(110,"2- Leia atentamente as condições e os detalhes da compra.");
                                    $pdf->Ln(2);
                                    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 11);
                                    $pdf->Write(130,"3- Apresentação do cupão no estabelecimento previsto.");

                                }
                                $file = $pdf->Output("","S");


                 $query = "INSERT INTO historico         (nomeUser,email,nomeVoucher,categoria,quantidade,preco,confirmacao,filePDF,idUser) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    $stmt = $mybd->prepare($query) or die("Erro na base de dados");
                    $ficheiro = addslashes($file);
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssiissi",$nomeUser,$email,$titulo,$nomeCategoria,$quantidade,$total,$confirmacao,$ficheiro,$idUser);
                    $stmt->execute();               
                    $stmt->close();
```

When I want to retrieve it, I can't show my content and the adobe tell me "Fail to loading pdf"
I'm using the following code to read content from database:

```
         $query = "select nomeUser,email,nomeVoucher,categoria,preco,confirmacao,filePDF
                            from historico
                            Where confirmacao = 'a confirmar'

                            LIMIT $start, $per_page"; 
                  $stmt = $mybd->prepare($query);   
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($nomeUser,$email,$nomeVoucher, $categoria, $preco, $confirmacao,$filePDF);
             while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if($confirmacao == "a confirmar"){
            echo("<tbody >");           
            echo("<tr>
                    <td>$nomeUser</td>");
              echo "<td>$email</td>";
              echo("<td>$nomeVoucher</td>");
              echo("<td>$categoria</td>");
              echo("<td>$preco €</td>");
              echo("<td>$confirmacao</td>");
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $nomeVoucher .'.pdf');
                echo $row['data'];
                die();
              echo"<input type='hidden' name='mail' value='0' />";
              echo "<th><input type='checkbox' name='mail' value='1'></th>";
              echo("</tr>");
              echo("</tbody>");
            }
        }
```

I can't found any answer to my problem.
Anyone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to mix HTML and binary output. What you'll need to do is set up a link in your HTML table, which points to a separate PHP script. In that separate script you can output the headers and **only** binary data.

**Edit:** Giving Example

In your html table, you'll to remove all `header()` and `die()` calls, and you'll need a link to the document:

`echo("<td><a href='getFile.php?nomeVoucher=".$nomeVoucher."'>Download</a>");`

Then create a new script called `getFile.php` in the same directory. It should look *somthing* like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['nomeVoucher'])) {
  $nomeVoucher = $_GET['nomeVoucher'];
} else {
  die("nomeVoucher missing.");
}

$query = "select filePDF
          from historico
          Where nomeVoucher = ?
          LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$stmt = $mybd->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['nomeVoucher']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($filePDF);
if($stmt->fetch()) {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($filePDF));
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $nomeVoucher .'.pdf');
    echo $filePDF;
    die();
} else {
    die("something broke");
}

?>
```

Keep in mind this is purely conceptual. I have not used mysqli extensively, especially with the `bind_result()` function, so this code assumes that your original example is at least getting and displaying some data correctly. It also assumes that `$filePDF` contains actual binary PDF data.

Comment: Well I don't understood your answer..Can you show me an example please?

Comment: If I do a var_dump on the variable $filePDF, show me the binary content and show me this errors: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... It shows me for all headers.

Comment: You may have unintended output before the blob data. Read my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816837/dynamic-image-creation-apache-headers-using-imagick/18001895#18001895 regarding output buffering, and trashing the cache.

Comment: I saw your answer and post after the result but still doesn't work